# Is it possible to connect to the internet over wifi, but connect two computers over ethernet to pass files or other data in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, bridge, wired-networking

I'm trying to share an internet connection from a host computer's wifi to another computer connected via ethernet while also allowing both computers to directly talk to each other over the wire. The goal is to have various programs work with each other quickly rather than rely on the wifi's connection as I often use them in tandem. I tried the internet connection settings but the host can only ping the other computer, not the other way around. A network bridge seems like the best option, but that doesn't seem to allow access to the internet over wifi even though Windows says I'm still connected to my router. I've also tried both setting the bridge's IP to that of the unbridged wifi connection, a unique IP, and DHCP but none allow internet. The computers also don't seem to talk to each other. All drivers appear to be up to date.

Is this kind of connection possible? Appreciate any help or troubleshooting tips!

Per request, here are a couple of diagrams.

- [This is the ideal setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BbbP.png)
- [This will also work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQN4Y.png)

Comment: How are the computers connected to each other, please provide a diagram with HW connections and logical setup.

Comment: @Albin Apologies for the delay! Added the diagrams.

Comment: Have you enabled internet connection sharing on the host pc?  This sounds like a no-brainer but I get that I probably don't understand what you are getting at.  I have a PC that uses the wifi connection from another PC using internet connection sharing.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Appreciate the reply! I have tried that, but I could only seem to ping from host to the other PC, but not the PC to the host. This made it so my keyboard/mouse sharing program could not create a connection. I think the sharing also removes NAT, so if I were to use a game console with it (my PC has a much better wifi connection than my consoles), then it could make it too strict for games. I could very easily be missing a setting somewhere though.

Comment: Connecting Router<-Wifi->PC1<-Ethernet->PC2 is not a common setup but should work in general. There should be a few instructions on the internet. Make sure you use the right one, most tell you how to share internet if your host PC is connected via cable. But I think your easiest option would be to use a WiFi-Extender or a Router (note: not all routers can connect to the internet via wifi) and connect both PCs to the new device via cable.